# How to change the fields that are required in login/register system of Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to change the default fields of the **template login/register system** of Laravel 5.2

For example, in the log in page, instead of using the registered e-mail address as username to log in, I want it to be a text field that requires the user to prompt the his/her registered username, not the his/her registered e-mail address.

Answer (score 0):

Validation / Storage Customization

> To modify the form fields that are required when a new user registers
>   with your application, or to customize how new user records are
>   inserted into your database, you may modify the AuthController class.
>   This class is responsible for validating and creating new users of
>   your application.
>
> The validator method of the AuthController contains the validation
>   rules for new users of the application. You are free to modify this
>   method as you wish.
>
> The create method of the AuthController is responsible for creating
>   new App\User records in your database using the Eloquent ORM. You are
>   free to modify this method according to the needs of your database.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

Comment: yes, for registering the new users that is the case. but the problem is about logging in the user using a custom field (e.g. username field) instead of the template's e-mail address field.

Comment: Its the same controller: AuthController